# Django queryset with one-to-many relationships attached in one query

Tags: sql, django

I have a queryset of model `A`. Each instance of model `A` is in a one-to-many relationship with model `B`. I can get the instances of model `B` associated with an instance of model `A` by doing `A.b_set.all()` but is there a way to attach the results of `b_set.all()` to each instance of a queryset run on `A`, maybe with an annotation?

I am using Django `2.0`

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "*attach the result to each instance of a queryset run on `A`*"?

Comment: I want to iterate over the `A` queryset and it would be nice if each instance in the queryset had as a property the `B` queryset corresponding to `b_set.all()`

Comment: Perhaps you can add a `@property` such that `an_a.b_all`, is a "shortcut" for `an_a.b_set.all()`. Actually the idea behind `b_set` is that it is a *manager*: it allows to `.filter(..)` etc, and thus make it more efficient if you do *not* need all related `B` instances.

Comment: Probably you are looking for prefetch_related: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related